# If the defense commits a penalty on an extra point after a turnover does the offense get to retry the point?

Tags: rules, american-football, officiating, nfl

If the defense commits a penalty on an extra point after a turnover does the offense get to retry the point?

Assume the offense is going for a two point conversion and a defender intercepts the ball.

One of his teammates hoping to help out commits a holding penalty *after* the interception.

Does the offense get to retry the extra point or does this penalty have to be enforced on the next kickoff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything in the rules that suggest that the offense (team A) would not be able to accept the penalty and retry.

There are specific rules that apply when both teams foul and there is a change of possession (11-3-3-6).  Therefore, I presume that the rules for when only the defense (team B) fouls will apply in cases where there is and is not a change of possession.

From 11-3-3-4 ([NFL Rulebook)](http://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/2016-nfl-rulebook/#section-3-try)

> Item 4. Fouls by Team B. The following applies if there is a foul by
>   Team B:
>
> All fouls will result in the distance penalty being assessed on the
>   ensuing kickoff, unless Team A chooses to attempt a retry after
>   enforcement of the penalty, or the penalty negates a score by Team B.
>
> If the foul results in a safety, Team A is awarded one point.
>
> Note: If the foul is for defensive pass interference, and it is
>   declined, no distance penalty is enforced on the kickoff.

Comment: I mostly agree with this answer, though I don't think the answer is what should be the result.  It does seem to be what the rulebook says, though.  If you go to the next item (fouls by both teams), that reads as you'd expect (if both fouls occur after the change of possession, then the try is not repeated); so I would expect a change of possession to end the try, regardless of the result after.  But they're very specific with Team A in this case (post-change of possession foul is a kickoff distance penalty unless Team A scores), so I guess this is what is intended.

Answer (score -2):

I think there's 2 points in here:

An extra point, or Try, is really independent of how the Touchdown was scored - it is a "free" un-timed down that is independent of a series.  If the defense (Team B) commits a penalty, in most cases the offense (Team A) can accept the penalty and retry the down.

In the example you gave, because a turnover was committed on the un-timed down, THEN the penalty occurred, I legit believe Team A get's away with one, because there's no enforcement since the play is independent of a series of downs.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, misunderstands the question, and does not cite the rulebook, which is an expectation on answers to questions of this nature.  Here, Team B is the one committing the foul, not Team A; and fouls on the Try are penalized on kickoff if they don't cause a repeat of the try.